Run VB.Script from CATVBA
i want to run the existing VB.Script(in Desktop foloder) from CATVBA. I tried with some code, but i couldn't not able to execute it.
Sub Atuoamtion6()
    Dim CATIA As Object
    Set CATIA = CreateObject("CATIA.Application")

    Dim productDocument As Object
    Set productDocument = CATIA.ActiveDocument

    Dim product As Object
    Set product = productDocument.product

    Dim components As Object
    Set components = product.Products

    Dim component As Object
    Dim componentName As String

    Dim macroPath As String
    macroPath = "C:\Users\mvinot22\Desktop\PPM\CADXX.catvbs" ' Update with your actual macro path

    On Error GoTo HandleError ' Add error handling

    For Each component In components
        ' Get the name of the component
        componentName = component.Name

        ' Clear the selection
        productDocument.Selection.Clear

        ' Select the current component
        productDocument.Selection.Add component

        ' Open the component in a new window
        CATIA.StartCommand "Open in New Window"

        ' Execute the CATIA macro using ExecuteFile method
        CATIA.SystemService.ExecuteFile macroPath

        ' Close the new window
        CATIA.ActiveWindow.Close
    Next component

Exit Sub

HandleError:
    MsgBox "Error executing script: " & Err.Description
    Resume Next ' Continue to the next component or exit the loop
End Sub

Also tried with
' Execute the CATVBS script using Shell
Shell "wscript.exe " & scriptPath

' Execute the CATVBS script
Dim scriptPathVariant As Variant
scriptPathVariant = CStr(scriptPath) ' Ensure it's a string
CATIA.SystemService.ExecuteScript scriptPathVariant, Null


You are running a catvba macro, wo why are you creating a new catia instance (CreateObject)?

i am trying to run the macro after i open the application.

ExecuteScript requires several parameters to start a script.
Here an Example to start a catvbs.
Sub CATMain()

    Dim PathToFolder as String
    Dim ScriptFileName as String
    Dim RoutineName as String
    Dim params() as Variant

    PathToFolder = "D:\test\"
    ScriptFileName = "MyTestScript.catvbs"
    RoutineName = "CATMain"

    CATIA.SystemService.ExecuteScript PathToFolder, catScriptLibraryTypeDirectory , ScriptFileName, RoutineName, params

End Sub

